# Remove duplicate rows after inner join

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates

I have got couple of duplicate rows after doing the join

```
WITH a
AS (SELECT sh.StateTime,
           sh.ObjectID,
           State,
           sh.StateType,
           sh.Output
    FROM dbo.mon2_Statehistory AS sh
        JOIN mon2_Objects AS o
            ON o.ObjectID = sh.ObjectID
    WHERE CAST(sh.StateTime AS DATE) = '2020-11-30'
          AND o.ObjecttypeID = 2
          AND sh.State > 0
          AND sh.StateType = 1),
     b
AS (SELECT DISTINCT
           h.HostID,
           h.Alias AS HostName,
           h.DisplayName AS HostDisplayName,
           ssp.objectid,
           ssp.HostObjectID,
           ssp.displayname AS ServiceDescription,
           ssp.state_text,
           ssp.state
    FROM dbo.mon2_ServiceStatePeriods AS ssp
        JOIN dbo.mon2_Hosts AS h
            ON h.HostObjectID = ssp.HostObjectID
    WHERE ssp.state_text <> 'OK'
          AND ssp.state > 0
          AND ssp.ReportingMonth = '2020-11')
SELECT b.HostID,
       b.objectid,
       b.HostName,
       b.HostDisplayName,
       b.ServiceDescription,
       a.StateTime,
       a.State,
       a.Output,
       a.StateType,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.HostID ORDER BY b.HostID)
FROM a
    JOIN b
        ON b.objectid = a.ObjectID
WHERE b.HostName = 'atvie1fs003'
      AND a.State = 2;
```

The output column is a text type so that i can not use DISTINCT or GROUP BY. I have also tried

`ROW NUMBER () OVER PARTITION ()` but did not get the results

What wrong I have done in the CTE tables ?

[image: duplicate_result]

Comment: Why are you *still* using `text`, it's been deprecated for 15 years now.

Comment: @Larnu actually i was also curious. Some one did it 3 years back. 
i have altered the data type and now i can use group by to remove the duplicated.